# Kill multiple processes running from a given path on remote machine

Tags: powershell, vbscript, wmi, kill-process

I have a following problem:
I'm in need of a code that will close all running process from a given path on a remote machine.

So far I've found and came up with those 2 lines but none of them actually work.

```
Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Path -like "\\$computername\C$\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Reader 10.0\Reader\**"} | Stop-Process -Force
```

This is the second line I've found but still does not want to work with me :)

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -Filter "ExecutablePath LIKE '\\$computername\C$\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Reader 10.0\Reader\'" -ComputerName $computername | Invoke-WmiMethod -Name Terminate
```

I will be happy to get some advice. Belive that this is something rather simple to do..I hope that is.. :)

Comment: i would try using the `-computername` parameter of gwmi and then specify a local path, you are querying your local pc for processes with a path located on a remote computer and i dont think thats what you wanted to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_Process -ComputerName  $computerName | ?{ $_.ExecutablePath -like "*Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Reader 10.0\Reader*" }).Terminate()
```

You might have to tweak the "like" expression, however.

Comment: Paul, David - thanks a bunch! With your help I was able to make everything work :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way to approach this is to run that command local to the machine with PSRemoting.

```
Invoke-Command $computername -script {
    Get-Process | Where-Object {$_.Path -like "c:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe Reader 10.0\Reader\*"} | Stop-Process -Force  
}
```